# Rotar rueda mediante la fuerza de presión

Tags: javascript, html5, css

¿Cómo rotarlo mediante la fuerza de empuje?, ahora funciona con doble click, pero ¿cómo hacerlo que rote empujando el ratón?.

> Debería moverse la rueda como si se arrojara un objeto
>   horizontalmente.
>
> Arrastrando el raton, la rueda debe girar, una ves el raton suelto, la
>   rueda debe moverse una distancia X dependiendo a la fuerza o tiempo de
>   arrastre del raton.
>
> para generar la distancia X, se tiene que usar las formulas de fisica
>
> d=v*t
>
> ```
>  siendo: d=distancia, 
>          v=velocidad de arrastre del ratón, 
>          t(t1)=tiempo de arrastre del ratón
> ```
>
> de esa manera hallamos la distancia recorrida.
>
> El tiempo de la animación debe ser dependiente de la distancia
>   recorrida,  este tiempo de animación no es el mismo tiempo t1(ver en
>   formula),
>
> **Entonces como hallamos t(tiempo de animacion)?**
>
> teniendo:  la distancia
>
> la velocidad(velocidad del raton obtenido anteriormente y que se vaya disminuyendo gradualmente)
>
> podemos hallar el tiempo de animación (con la misma formula de arriba)
>
> **d/v=t**

Pueden hacer la prueba haciendo doble click en la rueda

```js
$("#item").dblclick(function() {
  $("#item").animate({
    left: 90
  }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');  
    },
    duration: 3000
  });
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-image: url('http://icon-icons.com/icons2/37/PNG/512/wheel_theapplication_2969.png');
  border-radius: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item" ></div>
```

Comment: quieres usar jquery?

Comment: @rnd puede ser js puro o jquery no hay problema

Comment: ¿A que te refieres cuando dices "empujando el ratón"?

Comment: @Error404 arrastrar un poco el raton para que rote, me explico si se presiona(empuja) por 1 seg dara 3 vueltas la rueda, si se presiona por 2 seg la rueda dara 6 vueltas. etc

Comment: te interesa una solución con box2d y canvas?

Comment: @rnd con tal que funcione bienvenido

Comment: @rn3w que vas a hacer con esto despues? para que tipo de app es? es solo una animación o es un juego? la respuesta depende pues si vas a hacer un juego, con CSS quizá puedas hacer esto, pero cuando empieces a dar mas complejidad al juego css no va a servir y si vas a necesitar un cambio, mejor que sea temprano.

Comment: @rnd solo es para una aplicacion que es muy simple, no es nada complejo como un juego

Comment: @rn3w ok, pero no querras despues detectar si la rueda chocha contra el borde o contra un obstaculo... cierto?

Comment: @rnd no, solamente quiero que realice lo que pregunte y con eso sera suficiente para la logica de la funcionalidad de mi aplicacion

Comment: @rn3w con empujando quieres decir que aprietas el boton del mouse, luego lo desplazas y la rueda se mueve en la direccion que "se empujo el mouse" por ende, depende la velocidad de la fuerza utilizada ? (osea cuando se suelta el mouse) una especie de drag and drop?

Comment: @rnd claro estas en lo cierto!!!

Comment: ahora si entendi la description :)

Comment: ¿Cómo determinar la distancia a recorrer o el tiempo? Velocidad se puede obtener con el movimiento del ratón, pero no durante cuánto tiempo debe durar la animación o cuánta distancia debe recorrer.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el tiempo de la animación debe ser dependiente  de la distancia recorrida, creo que les confundi con el tiempo de arrastre del ratón

Comment: @rn3w ¿y de dónde lo sacamos?¿nos lo inventamos? Es realmente difícil trabajar en un problema en el que la persona proporciona información con cuentagotas y parece que le duele darla más que un dolor de muelas. Las descripciones que das están incompletas o son directamente malas. Es muy difícil y frustrante ayudarte de esa manera.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro modifique la descripción, pense que se entendía, mil disculpas

Answer (score 11):

Esta respuesta va a contener dos posibles soluciones:

1. si quieres lanzar la rueda: que se mueva una vez se suelte el ratón, dependiendo de la distancia y tiempo pulsado; y
2. si quieres empujar la rueda: que se mueva con el ratón mientras éste esté pulsado.

La idea en ambos casos es bastante similar. Escuchar cuando se pulsa el ratón sobre la rueda y a partir de ahí hacer cálculos para moverla cuando corresponda. Aquí te dejo las dos opciones.

### Lanzar la rueda

Si lo que quieres es lanzar la rueda, es decir, que no se mueva mientras el ratón se está moviendo, si no que la animación dependa de la distancia recorrida y el tiempo que se haya tenido pulsado el ratón, puedes hacer algo parecido a esto:

- Detectar cuando el ratón se pulsa sobre la rueda y guardar:

  - La posición inicial del ratón (usando `clientX`)
  - El tiempo en el que se pulsó la rueda (con `getTime()`)
- Cuando el ratón se deja de pulsar, si cuando se pulsó fue sobre la rueda, hacer lo siguiente:

  - Obtener la posición actual del ratón
  - Obtener el tiempo en el que se soltó el ratón
  - Calcular la distancia y dirección (posición actual - posición inicial del ratón)
  - Animar la rueda con el mismo tiempo que el ratón estuvo pulsado, teniendo en cuenta su posición actual, la distancia y la dirección.

El código sería así:

```js
var movimiento = 0;
var origen = 0;
var tiempo = 0;

$(document).on("mouseup", function(e) { 
  if (movimiento) {
   movimiento = 0;
    
    var distancia = e.clientX - origen;
    var fin = new Date().getTime();
    var diftiempo = fin - tiempo;

    $("#item").stop().animate({
     left: (parseInt($("#item").css("left")) + distancia) + "px",
    }, {
     step: function(now, fx) {
       $("#item").css("transform", "rotate(" + now + "deg)")
      }, 
      duration: diftiempo
    })
  }
});

$("#item").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  movimiento = 1;
  origen = e.clientX;
  tiempo = new Date().getTime();
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-image: url('http://icon-icons.com/icons2/37/PNG/512/wheel_theapplication_2969.png');
  border-radius: 300px;
  transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item" ></div>
```

Eso hará que la animación dure tanto como el tiempo que haya estado pulsado el ratón, si lo que quieres es que el tiempo que haya estado pulsado el ratón sea un "indicador de fuerza" (más tiempo = animación más rápida) lo que tendrás que hacer es añadir un valor máximo y entonces calcular el tiempo de animación basándote en ese valor máximo - el tiempo que haya estado pulsado el ratón.

---

### Empujar la rueda

En este caso, la idea es que sólo se moverá y rotará la rueda cuando el ratón esté pulsado y se mueva (empujando o tirando). Para ello:

- Cuando el ratón se pulsa sobre la imagen:

  - Guardo la posición actual del ratón (`clientX`)
  - Guardo la posición actual de la rueda
- Al mover el ratón:

  - Se calcula la diferencia entre la posición actual del raton y la original donde se pulsó
  - La diferencia se resta a la posición de la rueda
  - Se asigna ese valor al ángulo que debe rotar la rueda (suponiendo que la posición inicial es `left:0` como hice, de otro modo, tendrás que realizar cálculos adicionales.

Éste sería el código (podría limpiarse si en lugar de usar variables globales usases variables o atributos asociados al elemento, lo que te permitiría animar varios elementos de forma independiente):

```js
var movimiento = 0;
var origen = 0;
var izquierda = 0;

$(document).on("mouseup", function(e) { movimiento = 0; });

$("#item").on("mouseup", function(e) {
  movimiento = 0;
}).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  movimiento = 1;
  origen = e.clientX;
  izquierda = parseInt($(this).css("left"))
}).on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (movimiento){    
    var diff = e.clientX - origen;
    $this.css("left", (izquierda + diff) + "px");
    $this.css("transform", "rotate(" + (izquierda+diff) + "deg)");
  }
});
```

```css
#item {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: #000;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-image: url('http://icon-icons.com/icons2/37/PNG/512/wheel_theapplication_2969.png');
  border-radius: 300px;
  transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item" ></div>
```

Comment: Hey!!  tengo mi rta a medio hacer, pero es algo parecido a una rueda de la fortuna.. jaja. Bastante difil de interpretar el concepto. :P

Comment: Ahora que lo releo, también podría ser como dices. Espero a ver tu respuesta

Comment: @rnd si se parece mucho a una ruleta, pero tendria que avanzar depende a la fuerza una distacia x

Comment: @rn3w entonces esta respuesta realmente no te vale, ¿no? Sería que según cuánto se haya movido el ratón gire la rueda (sin realmente moverse del sitio)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es la mejor aproximacion tu respuesta, pero la rueda se mueve con el raton, deberia moverse como si se arrojara un objeto horizontalmente

Comment: @rn3w debes aclarar todo eso en la pregunta. No está nada claro porque no hablas de tirar o arrojar, si no de empujar (que sería más parecido a lo que yo puse)